# How do I write a macro to rewrite subcripting. Eg rewriting`\smartind ABC_i` to `ABC_{(i)}`

Tags: macros, xparse

I am messing around with subscripting and how I want to format various things around it.

So I want to prepend my subscripted expressions with a macro, that will give me access to the items before, and after  the underscore.

For example:

making it do:

- `\smartind A_b`  be the same as `A_(b)`
- `\smartind ALPHABET_b`  be the same as `ALPHABET_(b)`

I feel like this is a job for `xparse`

#### p.s.

For interest this is what I ended up doing with it in final form: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/183255/a-smart-subscript-indexing-macro

Answer (score 6):

You can use the parameter text specification with `\def` to identify the exact pattern to expect; it probably functions similarly to [`xparse`](//ctan.org/pkg/xparse)'s `u{<token>}` argument specification:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\smartind#1_#2{#1_{(#2)}}

\begin{document}

$A_b \quad \smartind A_b$

$AB_c \quad \smartind AB_c$

$ABC_{def} \quad \smartind ABC_{def}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: wow,  did not expect this in pure unaugmented TeX. Does it come in `\newcommand` flavor?

Comment: @LyndonWhite: No, the traditional `\newcommand` in LaTeX doesn't provide a parameter specification that identifies a specific pattern, but `\def`-and-friends do.

Answer (score 3):

Simple case is to just eat the `_` as a mandidory argument

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\smartind}{m m m}{
%   \ifstrequal{#2}{_}{}{\errmessage{Expected underscore (not #2) between #1 and #3}} 
% the above line requires etoolbox, uncomment it to assert that the _ is inplace
    \ind{#1}{#2}
}
```

That would work for `\smartind A_b`, but you would have to write `\smartind {ALPHABET}_b`

What you are actually after is the **until** specifier for [xparse](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.pdf):

> `u` Reads an argument “until”`〈tokens〉`
>   are encountered, where the desired`〈tokens〉`
>   are given as an argument to the specifier:
>   `u{tokens}`

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\smartind}{u{_} m}{
        #1_{(#2)}
}
```

Works great